# GCP flush redis if memory above 90%

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-memorystore

Is there a way to flush my GCP Redis when a trigger is triggered?

In my specific case, I'm using the Google StackDriver metrics to monitor and get notified. I want that when my Redis memory is above 90% it will automatically flush.
Is there a way to perform this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling a Basic Tier instance flushes the cache so my suggestion is to configure the instance with a smaller cap (& appropriate eviction policy) then have it scale as needed.

`gcloud redis instances update instance-id --update-redis-config maxmemory-policy=policy`

Alternatively, you can setup a web service to make the appropriate CLI command, but this requires a little more effort.